# MySQL Error:Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

Tags: php, mysql

I am running an SQL query containing the following bit of code:

```
IF(oa.affiliatetrack REGEXP '|MB[1-6]', ((ol.item_price_exVat * oloq.oq_item_qty) * 0.08) *1.20, ((ol.item_price_exVat * oloq.oq_item_qty) * 0.06) *1.20) as Original_Commission
```

When this run on MySQl it works fine. When I move to a Linux server that automatically runs the script through PHP it returns me this error:

> MySQL Error:Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp

What does this mean? And how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code string for REGEXP **'`|MB[1-6]`'** has symbol **`|`**

That symbol work like *or* for searching variants, so `|MB[1-6]` has next searching variants:

- - empty string (this is generate error in your case)
- `MB1`
- `MB2`
- `MB3`
- `MB4`
- `MB5`
- `MB6`

If you need `|` like text part in searching string use `\|`